# Setting many rows new field to a specific value based on another field in one query

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I'm adding a new column to my `CountryCodes` table, `phoneCodes`. I want to add each country's phone code based on the `numericCode` that already exists in the table. Is there a way to do this without doing a SET for each country? It seems inefficient to do:

```sql
UPDATE TABLE `CountryCodes`
SET `phoneCode` = 1
WHERE `numericCode = 840
...
/* Do this for each country?*/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `case` expression:

```
update table countrycodes
    set phonecode = (case when numericCode = 840 then 1
                          . . .
                     end)
    where numericCode in (840, . . .);
```